# Verification of Python(x,y) installer

Tags: python, code-signing, install

I'm an Aerospace Engineer just starting out in my field, I'm planning to start using Python, but I've run into a bit of a conundrum. I downloaded `Python(x,y)-2.7.10.0.exe` Windows installer from [here](http://pythonxy.connectmv.com/Python(x,y)-2.7.10.0.exe) (I found that link on the [Official GitHub page](https://python-xy.github.io/downloads.html)), but the executable is unsigned.

Is there any way to verify the authenticity of the executable? Anybody else used this and had problems?

Comment: Did you try to ask the developers if they provide signed binaries?

Comment: I can't find contact info for the dev. Unfortunately, it looks like this may be a dead project as its last update was over two years ago. I'm likely going to grab a different distribution. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No need to delete the question. It may prove useful to someone else who is wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your question and [comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180790/verification-of-pythonx-y-installer#comment350711_180790):

1. If you think that the mirror you used could have been compromised, you can download the file from the other 2 mirrors available there and compare the hashes (md5 or sha1) of the downloaded files, the probability of all three sites being hacked is not very high and could help you to feel safer about it.
2. Checking the official website, I found the `History` section, here you can find the names of the developer and the maintainer.

[image: History section]

If you search for these names on Google, you will be able to find their personal profiles, you can ask them if they provide signed binaries as @Arminius said, 
or ask them to provide you with the original file, also you can ask them the hash value to compare with the file that you downloaded.

- Gabi Davar (Maintainer since 2011):

  - [LinkedIn](https://il.linkedin.com/in/gabi-davar-615678)
  - [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/users/17717/gabi-davar)
  - [Github](https://github.com/mindw)
  - [Google+](https://plus.google.com/+GabiDavar)
- Pierre Raybaut (Original Developer):

  - [Twitter](https://twitter.com/pierreraybaut)
  - [Github](https://github.com/PierreRaybaut)

Hope it helps.